# How can I save HtmlDocument to memory? Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML Agility Pack to parse and HTML document, make a change to a node, and then save the HTML document. I would like to save the document to memory so I can write the HTML out as a string later in the application. My current implementation always returns a string == "". I can see that the HtmlDocument object is not empty when debugging. Can someone provide some insight?

```
private string InitializeHtml(HtmlDocument htmlDocument)
    {
        string currentUserName = User.Identity.Name;
        HtmlNode scriptTag = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script[@id ='HwInitialize']");
        scriptTag.InnerHtml = 
            string.Format("org.myorg.application = {{}}; org.myorg.application.init ={{uid:\"{0}\", application:\"testPortal\"}};",currentUserName);

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        htmlDocument.Save(memoryStream);
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, it would be easier to write to a [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs9kt2e9.aspx) instead if all you want is the string of the HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

Before creating the `StreamReader` and calling `ReadToEnd()`

The stream pointer is likely getting left at the end of the stream by the `Save` method (it's best practise for a component to do this - in case *you* want to append more data to the stream) therefore when you call `ReadToEnd`, it's already at the end and nothing gets read.

Comment: Ahh yes. I see now that save was leaving the stream at the end. Thanks!

Comment: I faced issue of incomplete data in memoryStream. To get html of page, write it directly to StringWriter as other comment also mentions.
`using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                doc.DocumentNode.WriteTo(sw);
                sw.Flush();
                return sw.ToString();
            }`